# ScalaTest does not pass even if conditions are verified

Tags: scala, scalatest

Can anybody explain how sentences like this can appear in my test report?

**"List(Array(109, 121, 75, 101, 121)) was not equal to List(Array(109, 121, 75, 101, 121))"**

Here is the full output

```
Run starting. Expected test count is: 4
Ws2redisAdapterTest:
Ws2redisAdapter
- should recognize 1-arity commands
- should recognize 2-arity commands *** FAILED ***
  List(Array(109, 121, 75, 101, 121)) was not equal to List(Array(109, 121, 75, 101, 121)) (Ws2redisAdapterTest.scala:15)
- should recognize N-arity commands *** FAILED ***
  List(Array(109, 121, 90, 115, 101, 116), Array(48), Array(45, 49)) was not equal to List(Array(109, 121, 90, 115, 101, 116), Array(48), Array(45, 49)) (Ws2redisAdapterTest.scala:
21)
- should throw Exception if an empty string is popped
Run completed in 298 milliseconds.
Total number of tests run: 4
Suites: completed 1, aborted 0
Tests: succeeded 2, failed 2, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
*** 2 TESTS FAILED ***
```

These are my tests in code:

```
package eu.codesigner.finagle.ws2redis
import org.scalatest._

class Ws2redisAdapterTest extends FlatSpec with Matchers {

  "Ws2redisAdapter" should "recognize 1-arity commands " in {
    val (cmd, args) = Ws2redisAdapter.adaptRedisCommand("INFO")
    cmd should be("INFO")
    args should be(null)
  }

  it should "recognize 2-arity commands " in {
    val (cmd, args) = Ws2redisAdapter.adaptRedisCommand("GET myKey")
    cmd should be("GET")
    args should be(List("myKey".getBytes()))
  }

  it should "recognize N-arity commands " in {
    val (cmd, args) = Ws2redisAdapter.adaptRedisCommand("ZRANGE myZset 0 -1")
        cmd should be("ZRANGE")
        args should be(List("myZset".getBytes(),"0".getBytes(), "-1".getBytes() ))
  }

  it should "throw Exception if an empty string is given" in {
    a[Exception] should be thrownBy {
      Ws2redisAdapter.adaptRedisCommand("")
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equality on arrays is only defined as reference equality (like in Java). Therefore your test fails. You can check the equality of two arrays with `java.util.Arrays.equals`.

Comment: damn, this was a rookie mistake! :)
In order to still be able to use the "should be" I modified my test transforming the byte arrays to strings with map. 
From this:
     args should be(List("myKey".getBytes()))

to this:
    args.map(new String(_)) should be(List("myKey"))